# Cannot Access Hash Lookup Table In Perl Loop

Tags: perl, excel, hash

I am writing a Perl script that compares the data of two excel files.

I am currently taking in two columns of one of the excel files and storing it in a hash. The data I am using for the key is the email address, and the value is just another value in the excel sheet(unimportant). I am simply trying to store all of the emails as hash keys so that I can traverse another ('removals') excel file, and see whether the email exists in the original members table.

My intentions are something along these lines:

1) Create the hash and lookup array:

```
my %members_list;
foreach my $row (2..$MembersLastRow){
    $members_list{lc($Members->Cells($row,1)->{'Value'})} = lc($Members->Cells($row,2)->{'Value'}); 
}

my @removals_list;
foreach my $row (2..$RemovalsLastRow)
{
    push(@removals_list, lc($Removals->Cells($row,1)->{'Value'}));
}
```

2)Traverse the lookup array and check for existence in hash:

```
foreach my $key (sort @removals_list)
{
    print $key;
    if($members_list{$key}){
        print " - MATCH!";
    }
    print "\n";
}
```

The problem is that when I try to run this, there are never any matches. All of the elements in the removals list should be stored in the members_list hash. I have tried printing out the $members_list{$key} to the screen, and then it comes up with a "Uninitialized use of " blah blah blah.

I have been fighting with this for days now, any help is greatly appreciated.

THIS IS THE ENTIRE PAGE OF CODE THAT I AM USING!!!

```
use strict;
use 5.010;
use Win32::OLE qw(in with);
use Win32::OLE::Const 'Microsoft Excel';

$Win32::OLE::Warn = 3;                                # die on errors...

# get already active Excel application or open new
my $Excel = Win32::OLE->GetActiveObject('Excel.Application')
    || Win32::OLE->new('Excel.Application', 'Quit');  
$Excel->{DisplayAlerts}=0;   
# open Excel file

my $Book = $Excel->Workbooks->Open("**FILENAME1**"); 
my $Book2 = $Excel->Workbooks->Open("**FILENAME2**"); 

# You can dynamically obtain the number of worksheets, rows, and columns
# through the Excel OLE interface.  Excel's Visual Basic Editor has more
# information on the Excel OLE interface.  Here we just use the first
# worksheet, rows 1 through 4 and columns 1 through 3.


my $Members = $Book->Worksheets(1);
$Members->{Name} = "Members - Points";
my $Results = $Book->Worksheets(2);
$Results->{Name} = "Perl Results -Saved";

my $Removals = $Book2->Worksheets(1);
$Removals->{Name} = "Removals";

my $count=0;
my %members_list;
my @removals_list;

my $MembersLastRow = &findLastRow($Members);
print "After Members Last Row\n";
my $RemovalsLastRow = &findLastRow($Removals);
print "After Removals Last Row\n";

foreach my $row (2..$MembersLastRow)
{
    next unless defined $Members->Cells($row,1)->{'Value'};
    $members_list{lc($Members->Cells($row,1)->{'Value'})} = lc($Members->Cells($row,2)->{'Value'}); 
}
foreach my $row (2..$RemovalsLastRow)
{
next unless defined $Removals->Cells($row,1)->{'Value'};
push(@removals_list, lc($Removals->Cells($row,1)->{'Value'}));
}

#DO THE VLOOKUP
my $matches=1;
print "Now doing comparisons......\n";
$Results->Cells($matches,1)->{'Value'} = "Removal List";
$Results->Cells($matches,2)->{'Value'} = "Corresponding Member List";


foreach my $key (sort @removals_list)
{
    print $key;
    if($members_list{$key}){
        print " - MATCH!";
    }
    print "\n";
}

print "\nComparisons Complete.\n";

sub findLastRow
{
    $_[0]->UsedRange->Find({What=>"*",
    SearchDirection=>xlPrevious,
    SearchOrder=>xlByRows})->{Row};
}

sub findLastCol
{
    $_[0]->UsedRange->Find({What=>"*", 
    SearchDirection=>xlPrevious,
    SearchOrder=>xlByColumns})->{Column};
}

$Book->Save();
```

Comment: Use [Data::Dumper](http://perldoc.perl.org/Data/Dumper.html) which is a standard Perl module and have it dump out the contents of both the Members list and the Removal list. That'll show you why you might not be getting any matches.

Answer (score 2):

If the value you are storing may be undef, you want to do this instead:

```
if ( exists $members_list{$key} ) {
```

Are you certain that you are accessing the same %members_list hash?  That it hasn't gone out of scope or been replaced by a later `my %members_list`?

What does this show:

```
use Data::Dumper;
$Data::Dumper::Terse = $Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1;
print Data::Dumper::Dumper( { 'removals' => [ sort @removals_list ], 'members' => [ sort keys %members_list ] } );
```

?

Comment: I just tried that, but it does the same thing. I do not see how it has gone out of scope. I have no "my %members_list" after the inital one. 

It is is really annoying because I feel that this should be working.

I will mention the modules I am using:
use strict;
use 5.010;
use Win32::OLE qw(in with);
use Win32::OLE::Const 'Microsoft Excel';

Comment: @bOkeifus: added a question to my answer

Comment: Nevermind, I found the problem. The problem was not with the code at all. The problem was that this program is supposed to check the original file for a list of removals, and then remove them. I was testing the program out on a list that already had the removals missing. So when it wasn't finding anything, that is why I thought the code was broken. It was actually the samples I was using that caused the issue. I truly appreciate you looking into this with me, I thought it all looked well also, apparently we were both right!